# ramda set lensPath on array item changes array to object

Tags: ramda.js

```
const o = { a: [1,2,3] }

R.set(R.lensPath(['a',1]), 5, o)
```

the result is

```
{"a": {"0": 1, "1": 5, "2": 3}}
```

but it should be

```
{ a: [1,5,3] }
```

How do I get the correct result?

Comment: Are you using an old version of Ramda?  This works correctly [in recent versions](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20o%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%20%7D%0A%0AR.set%28R.lensPath%28%5B%27a%27%2C1%5D%29%2C%205%2C%20o%29).

Comment: correct, the repl I used has "v=0.22.1" in the url. Thanks! also, the index in the lensPath has to be a number, if it's a string, it will produce the object

Comment: If you don't use that URL parameter, you'll get the latest version published.  The number-vs-string distinction is intentional.  If you pass a string, we simply assume it's an object parameter.  That allows you to do either.